# Transactions confirmation received , but table remains empty

Tags: postgresql

In my application, i write transactions to post gres schema `prod`.

In order to debug, I have using the `psql` command line client on OSX

My table the only fields I have to fill are the are message field (json blob) and and status field (text).

Here is what the schema looks like

```
                                                    Table "prod.suggestions"
      Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |      Default       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id               | uuid                     |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4() | plain    |              | 
 message          | jsonb                    |           | not null |                    | extended |              | 
 status           | text                     |           | not null |                    | extended |              | 
 transaction_hash | text                     |           |          |                    | extended |              | 
 created_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  | plain    |              | 
 updated_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "suggestions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Triggers:
    update_updated_at_on_prod_suggestions BEFORE UPDATE ON prod.suggestions FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_updated_at()
```

here is the function the trigger executes:

```
create function update_updated_at()
  returns trigger
as
$body$
  begin
    new.updated_at = current_timestamp;
    return new;
  end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Here is query to write the message:

```
INSERT INTO prod.suggestions (message, status) VALUES ('{"name": "Paint house", "tags": ["Improvements", "Office"], "finished": true}' , 'rcvd');
```

It returns `INSERT 0 1` which I assume is a sucesss.

however when i query the table, it doesnt return anything.

`select * from prod.suggestions;`

I will appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Are you running in a specific language/platform? Probably you're running but not commiting your transaction. Please provide more info.

Comment: I was intially running it on node, now I am using the console i.e `psql <connection_String>` and its still not working

Comment: Your table have a trigger, can you check what this trigger do? Maybe this trigger do something that deletes the line inserted.

Comment: The trigger updates the the current row `updated_at` field with a timestamp.  I will add the trigger code to my question @WilliamPrigolLopes

Comment: is it possible that function in the wrong  are in the wrong namespace? i.e the trigger is in prod and cannot reach the function?

Comment: I believe that the problem is related with your trigger. I created it here on a dummy table and the `updated_at` field did not worked. I believe that you need to do an update on table inside your trigger

Comment: does the mean the function is wrong or the trigger? from what i understand, the trigger runs on the table

```    update_updated_at_on_prod_suggestions BEFORE UPDATE ON prod.suggestions FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_updated_at()
```

Comment: No problems with your trigger, double checked here.

Comment: Another approach, try to run `SET SEARCH PATH='prod';` so, your default schema will be `prod`.  If something was not considering the search path, this will solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with postgres. I have another workers thread that was deleting all the data from the table.